# misleading project reactor documentation image for flatMapSequentialDelayError, or ...?

Tags: project-reactor

I've seen this on images multiple times, and just don't get it at all. Here is the javadoc:

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMapSequentialDelayError-java.util.function.Function-int-int-

image in question(sorry, I'm unable to show it directly)

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/doc-files/marbles/flatMapSequentialWithConcurrencyAndPrefetch.svg

Can someone explain, why is there 1 red square box? Why it's internal Flux was completed so soon? Based on what (in original flux) if purple is still emitted? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is correct as far as I can tell.

> What am I missing?

You seem to be assuming that the `flatMapSequential()` call is somehow affecting when the fluxes end, or when they emit their elements - the red flux ending after only one element and the others continuing for two. This isn't the case - this is just an example of what happens when you call `flatMapSequential()` on fluxes that just so happen to behave in this way.

If it helps, imagine they're 3 fluxes returning database records from a query. The green flux is subscribed to first, then it returns a result (but doesn't complete, because it's got another record to return still.) The red flux is then subscribed to, returns a result & completes (because there was only one record matching the query.) The Purple flux is then subscribed to, returns one result, then the green & purple fluxes return another result and then both complete.

In this case, if the red flux *didn't* complete, then the purple flux wouldn't be subscribed to until at least one of the green or red fluxes complete (since the max concurrency in this case its 2.) So picking fluxes that behave in this way for the example allows the image to be concise, as well as demonstrating both the "sequential" and the "max concurrency" elements visually.

Comment: Thanks for answer,still don't get it. Ok,concurrency is 2,so internal fluxes are started for green and red we will read from "top-level" flux,next purple element only when either internal fluxes terminates. And all internal fluxes will be concatenated in order. No problem with that. The question is, what controls the internal flux life. Mabye I got it incorectly, but I see there, that circle is turned into flux producing 2 squares and then completes. So either termination is based on fce first parameter,mapper(and image is incorrect),or there must be something else what ends that internal flux

Comment: ... or ... Is it possible to flux to not complete if there wasn't error? So it was requested to turn circle to two squares and complete. What event can happen, so that whole flow continues, but that one internal flux ends partially agains't it's definition but without error? Sorry, total beginner here.

Comment: @MartinMucha Why do you think the red flux is ending "partially" against its definition? A flux may complete because of an error, it may complete "normally", or it may never complete. That's true generally, with or without flatMapSequential(). In this case we're dealing with 3 fluxes (one of each colour) that all return a set number of values and then complete. flatMapSequential() doesn't control how many values those fluxes return, or when they complete, that's entirely down to the fluxes themselves - it simply merges those values together.

Comment: maybe I misinterpret the image then. I read there, that flatMapSequential gets mapper, which turns 1 circle into 2 squares and completes. The red one does not behave like that. I cannot be error, since (IIUC) that would prevent purple from even starting. Maybe I'm taking that mapper function too strictly, it confused me in lots of operators. I understand what you say, but I probably have to remember, that the mapper function should be interpreted very leniently in those images. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: @MartinMucha Yes, I think you're interpreting it much too strictly - the circles just denote fluxes, which may return any number of elements (squares.) They're not guaranteed to return the same number of elements if they're the same shape at all.